# How to decode this rbf file?

Tags: file-format, binary

I am trying to decode [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KVdKyZa3sVUsO-VvbOW5VTHvvYRqSKqj/view?usp=sharing) file but so far I have no luck. I tried with binwalk and other decoders but still did not see a way of decoding. Any help, more than welcome. The file supposed to have GPS data.